# How do I get the git rev-list --count number from an external build.gradle.kts file?

Tags: gradle, groovy, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I wrote this function for Groovy Gradle (call it `functions.gradle`)

```
static def gitVersionCode() {
    return "git rev-list --count HEAD".execute().text.trim().toInteger()
}

ext {
    gitVersionCode = this.&gitVersionCode
}
```

Where I can just call `gitVersionCode()` from an external `build.gradle` file to get the revision count. I am trying to re-write this for kts, but I am having trouble with

a) calling it from another script, and

b) Executing the bash command and returning it as an integer. I was able to get this as a string, but not an int.

What It tried looks sort of like this (`functions.gradle.kts`)

```
val gitBuildNumber: String by lazy {
    val stdout = ByteArrayOutputStream()
    rootProject.exec {
        commandLine("git", "rev-list", "--count", "HEAD")
        standardOutput = stdout
    }
    stdout.toString().trim()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert your result to int using `.toInt()`

```
val gitBuildNumber: Int by lazy {
    val stdout = org.apache.commons.io.output.ByteArrayOutputStream()
    rootProject.exec {
        commandLine("git", "rev-list", "--count", "HEAD")
        standardOutput = stdout
    }
    stdout.toString().trim().toInt()
}
```